# passing radio value to php file using jquery and then insert to database

Tags: php, jquery

I am beginner in jquery "actually its my first code". i am working on stars rating system, the jquery part worked perfectly and it returns the value of rate. But when it comes to php code it did! i want to pass (rate variable) from (index.php) to (rate.php) file in order to insert it into (rate) table. please help me

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html class="ng-scope" ng-app="">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ca-pub-2074772727795809.js" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>
    <script src="js/analytics.js" async=""></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>please Rate:</h1>
    <script>
       $(function(){
            $(".stars").on("click", function(){
                    var rate = $(this).val();  
                    alert(rate);
                    });
                });
    </script>

    <fieldset id='starset' class="rating" name="star">
        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
        <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
        <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
        <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
        <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
        <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

rate.php:

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("HWP",$connect);

$rate=$_POST['val']
if (isset($rate) && !empty($rate)) 
    {
        $query1 = mysql_query("select rate_id FROM rate WHERE Rate_cust_id= 1");
        $f1 = mysql_num_rows($query1);
        if (mysql_num_rows($query1) > 0) 
        {
            echo $f1['rate_id'];
        }

         else 
        {
            $query2= mysql_query("insert into rate ( rate_value, rate_cust_id , rate_hw_id) VALUES ($rate, 4 , 2); ");
            if ($query2) {
                echo "0";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I found method called $.Post() but i couldn't know where to use it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Couple of pointers, your code (one which you have added doesn't show) you posting data to your server, without the associated HTML, $('.stars').on('click') doesn't make much sense. So please add your relevant HTML. Edit: Research on $.ajax(). On click you have to send your value to your server so you have to put $.post() or $.ajax() inside your on('click') block.

Comment: sorry for that mistake. appended. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AJAX` with `JQuery` to be able to send your value:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".stars").on("click", function() {
        var rate = $(this).val();
        $.post("rate.php", {
           val: rate
        },
        function(data, status) {
            // here you can get the data sent from PHP with data variable & the status of the request with status variable
            //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, please note using `PDO` or `mysqli` for your requests. `mysql` is deprecated and can be vulnerable about `SQL injections`.
If you want to still on `mysql` and to don't use `mysqli` or `PDO`, you can use this mysql function to escape strings from the user to prevent `SQL injection`:

```
$secure = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['val']);
```

Finally, please note that `$cus_id` variable isn't defined in your code, it should cause errors.

> *Remember*: **NEVER** trust the user

**Source (if needed)** : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

> *PS:* Ajax is a technique for sending `$_GET` or `$_POST` requests to a page

You can use `$.get` for your get requests and `$.post` for your post requests

Comment: Thanks for replay. actually index.php didn't get data, it send data to rate.php. And still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".stars").on("click", function(){
            var rate = $(this).val();  

            $.post('rate.php', {val: rate}, function(data){...})
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also mind the injection risk, escape and validate everything that comes from user, absolutely everything.